# The exact definition of a form

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, definition

I am studying Fulton's Algebraic Geometry book and I can't understand what a form is! Sometimes it factors a polynomial $F$ to something like:
$$F=f_0 + f_1 + f_2 +...+ f_m$$
and it calls $f_i$  a "form". What is the exact definition of a form?

Comment: "form" means "homogeneous polynomial".

Comment: Thus, for example, $x^2 + 3xy - 2yz$ is a form of degree $2$, since all terms have total degree $2$, but $x^2+3x^2y - 2yz$ is not a form

Comment: This is defined on the very first page of the book: "We call F *homogeneous*, or a *form*, of degree $d$, if all coefficients $a_{(i)}$ are zero except for monomials of degree $d$."

Comment: @ViktorVaughn, I have made a community wiki answer to this question so that it now has an answer based on the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Putting together the answers in the comments to the question:

Viktor Vaughn writes: This is defined on the very first page of the book: "We call F *homogeneous*, or a *form*, of degree $d$, if all coefficients $a_{(i)}$ are zero except for monomials of degree $d$."

Quasi writes: Thus, for example, $x^2+3xy−2yz$ is a form of degree $2$, since all terms have total degree $2$, but $x^2+3x^2y−2yz$ is not a form.

(Note that $3x^2y$ has degree $2+1=3$.)

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial.